# C++ queue to store multiple type objects

Tags: c++, oop, generics, inheritance, queue

My best idea so far is to use a base class and subclass it with different types of objects. In this case there are two subclasses with similar methods, so this seems logical. I store objects by upcasting to the base class, but I am having trouble when accessing the object with its subclass methods. Here is my header file and main method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define STATIC 0
#define DYNAMIC 1

// Base class Msg
class Msg {
  public:
    void set_type(int);
    int get_type();
    virtual std::string repr();
    virtual int* get_data();
  protected:
    int type;
};

// Derived class StaticMsg
class StaticMsg: public Msg {
  public:
    void set_data();
    std::string repr() override;
    int* get_data() override;
  protected:
    int data[10];
};

class DynamicMsg: public Msg {
  public:
    DynamicMsg();
    void set_data(int sz);
    std::string repr() override;
    int* get_data() override;
  protected:
    int len, *data;
};
```

---

```
int main(void) {
  StaticMsg smsg,new_smsg;
  DynamicMsg dmsg,new_dmsg;

  smsg.set_type(STATIC);
  smsg.set_data();
  dmsg.set_type(DYNAMIC);
  dmsg.set_data(21);

  queue <Msg> q;

  q.push(smsg);
  q.push(dmsg);

  cout <<q.front().get_type() << endl;
  // FIXME call to repr() is causing segmentation fault
  cout <<q.front().repr()<<endl;
  cout << "here!"<<endl;
}
```

How can I store two different classes in single data structure and access their original methods upon retrieving them?

Or are there any alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Object slicing** will happen here. Your `child` class object will be sliced to `base` class type since you are passing by value when you call push_back. You need to use `queue` of pointers or smart pointers of your base class.